# Highlight all occurrences of a word within Windows command line

Tags: batch-file

I will be muxing 100's of (.mkv)'s via mkvmerge command line (.bat) file and would like to know if it's possible to have all occurrences of the words warning and error highlighted in yellow(warning) and red(error) and or change the text color.
I tried this "[Setting Text Color in a Batch File](http://www.mailsend-online.com/blog/setting-text-color-in-a-batch-file.html)" but the outcome is not specific to what I'm trying to accomplish.
My batch as it is:

```
@echo off
cls
md output
for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
"mkvmerge" --track-name -1:"" --no-attachments --no-track-tags --no-global-tags --disable-track-statistics-tags --display-dimensions "0:1280x720" --language -1:eng --default-track -1:yes --compression -1:none --no-chapters -o output/"%%~na.mkv" -a 1 -d 0 -S "%%~na.mkv" --track-order 0:0,0:1 --language 0:eng --stracks 0 "%%~na.idx"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Hackoo for edit.

Comment: What does "I tried this" mean? You're going to have to read the output of mkvmerge with another `for` loop, try to match 'error' then call that command to change the output color, then echo the line, then change the color back...   btw. use PowerShell and it will be somewhat easier, although not fundamentally different. What are the errors and warnings - do they cause mkvmerge to exit with a different return code? That might be easier to test for.

Comment: "I tried this..." means I tried the example from that url and it was not what I wanted. It can only change the color of text or lines of text within the batch file. The error or warning will show only when muxing. Could you pls give an example of how the "for" loop could work.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me the results I was looking for...
MTEE [Mtee commandline utility](http://www.commandline.co.uk/mtee/index.html)

```
@echo off
md output
md results
for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
"mkvmerge" --track-name -1:"" --no-attachments --no-track-tags --no-global-tags --disable-track-statistics-tags --display-dimensions "0:1280x720" --language -1:eng --default-track -1:yes --compression -1:none --no-chapters -o output/"%%~na.mkv" -a 1 -d 0 -S "%%~na.mkv" --track-order 0:0,0:1 --language 0:eng --stracks 0 "%%~na.idx" 2>&1 | mtee/+ results\"%%~na.txt"
)

cls
findstr /a:04 Error "results\*.txt"
findstr /a:0E Warning "results\*.txt"
echo.
powershell -c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\Windows\Media\notify.wav").PlaySync();
echo The process is complete.
pause
exit
```